# How to echo a line while executing hive queries from files using beeline

Tags: beeline

I have a hive query that has an echo command to print something. Below is a sample HQL file

```
!echo 'Total records';
use testDB;
select count(*) from tempTable;
```

After executing the query from hive using the command `hive -f sample.hql > op.txt` I would get the below output in the op.txt file.

```
Total records
231
```

What I want to know is how to achieve the same from beeline. If I run the same sample.hql file from beeline using the command `beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/ --silent=true -f hive.hql > op.txt` it fails. Below is the error I have received

```
Unknown command: echo 'Total records';
```

Do anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple
Replace your `!echo 'Total records';` with `!sh echo "Total records";` in your `hive.hql` file. It will work.
Enjoy!

Comment: You are right but it will work only with Hive version 0.14 or later but what I had was 0.13. Anyhow thanks for your answer.

Comment: this post was regarding the beeline however you are asking a question from Hive. Nevertheless, I executed a similar query like you mentioned and I can get that executed successfully. But i did not understand `\"seperator\"` in your query. See my sample query that has worked for me `hive -database alexraj_testing -e 'desc sample; !echo ============; desc sample;'`

Comment: For me, `!sh echo "blah";` failed but `'!echo "blah";` works.  The behavior I observe is that the ! works like in `vim`, what comes next gets interpreted by the shell.  Since /bin/echo isn't a shell script (on my system, it's a compiled executable),  sh can't run /bin/echo as a script.